# Selenium Python crashes when running on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver, vps

Hi I have a script that scraps info from [11880.com](http://11880.com). The script works perfectly when is executed in my computer but always crashes after a few records in a Digital Ocean droplet.

Here are my computer specs:

- OS: macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3
- chromedriver 2.36

VPS specs:

- OS: Linux 4.4.0-112-generic
- chromedriver 2.36

Here's a screenshot of the error that the terminal outputs:
[image]

By the way, I already have this in my chromedriver options (cause I've already googled a lot about the issue and found this to be a solution but did not work for me):

```
  chrome_options = Options()  
  chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("/root/Downloads/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Chrome properly installed and using the same python version (2.7)?